# What is the equivalent command of "if {-s $file-name}" in tcl?

Tags: shell, tcl

How to check whether file exists but empty in tcl? I mean is there exists any equivalent command for that such as `if [ -s <file-name> ]` in shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use "file size". This returns an error if the file is doesn't exist, so you just catch that and you're good to go.

Answer (score 5):

Brian Fenton [has the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669757/what-is-the-equivalent-command-of-if-s-file-name-in-tcl/6670916#6670916). To express his idea as code:

```
proc -s {filename} {
  set rc [catch {file size $filename} size]
  return [expr {$rc == 0 && $size > 0}]
}

if {[-s $file]} {...}
```

Comment: I am doing the "cat" of files and then applying the above operation. If the file has text, then it is working fine. If the file is empty, it is marking as true but it should mark as false.

Comment: Heh, I like the way you named your proc "-s", so that it's literally identical to OP request. Nice!